# What is the code-coverage percentage on your project?

Tags: unit-testing, code-coverage

What is the % code-coverage on your project?  I'm curious as to reasons why.

Is the dev team happy with it? If not, what stands in the way from increasing it?

Stuart Halloway is one whose projects aim for 100% (or else the build breaks!). Is anyone at that level?

We are at a painful 25% but aspire to 80-90% for new code.  We have legacy code that we have decided to leave alone as it evaporates (we are actively re-writing).

Answer (score 3):

We run at 85% code coverage, but falling below it does not break the build.  I think using code coverage as an important metric is a dangerous practice.  Just because something is covered in a test does not mean the coverage is any good.  We try to use it as guidance for the areas we are weakly covered, not as a hard fact.

Comment: re: coverage is no guarantee. indeed, this is true. IMO, it is a useful tool as part of a mix

Answer (score 2):

80% is the exit criteria for the milestone. If we don't make it thrgouh the sprint (even though we do plan the time up front), we add it through the stabilization. We might take an exception for particular component or feature, but we open Pri 1 item for the next milestone.

During coding, code coverage is measured automatically on the daily build and the report is sent to the whole team. Anything that falls under 70% is yellow, under 50% is red. We don't fail the build currently, but we have a plan to add this in the next milestone.

Not sure what the dev happines has to do with unit testing. Devs are hired to build quality product and there should be a process to enforce minimum quality and way to measure it. If somebody is not happy about the process, they are free to suggest another way of validating their code, before it is integrated with the rest of the components.

Btw, we measure code coverage on automated scenario tests as well. Thus, we have three unmbers - unit, scenario and combined.

Comment: thanks for the reply, Franci.  Re: happiness, I was trying to ask about any tensions between the dev team and management. i.e. Often devs wish their coverage is higher.

Comment: @Michael Easter: I am yet to work at place where management would push back on having better quality control over the product. And I wouldn't actually want to work at such place.

Answer (score 1):

Our company goal is 80% statement coverage, including exception handling code. Personally, I like to be above 90% on all of the stuff I check in.

Comment: Typically, what is in the missing 20%?  Just curious.

Comment: That's a really good question. I can't speak for everyone else's code. In my own, the only statements that aren't covered are methods that you're forced to override and are used mainly for logging purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I often use code coverage under our automated test suite, but primarily to look for untested areas.  We get about 70% coverage most of the time, and will never hit 100% for two reasons;

1)  We typically automate new functionality **after** the release which is manually tested for it's first release and hence not included in coverage analysis.  Automation is primarily for functional regression in our case and is the best place to execute and tweak code coverage.

2)  Fault injection is required to get 100% coverage, as you need to get inside execption handlers.  This is difficult and time consuming to automate.  We don't currently do this and hence won't ever get 100%.  Jame's Whittakers books on [breaking software](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201796198) cover this subject well for anyone interested.

It is also worth remembering that code coverage does not equate to test coverage, as is regularly discussed in threads such as [this](http://www.sqaforums.com/showflat.php?Number=426373) and [this](http://www.sqaforums.com/showflat.php?Cat=0&Number=293776&an=&page=0&vc=1) over on SQAforums.  Thus 100% code coverage can be a mis-leading metric.

Comment: It is also worth remembering that 100% code coverage can only be a misleading metric once you have achieved it.  Once you are there, then you can look at improving your test coverage further.

Comment: Welcome, and no idea why it was voted down.  Possibly that we don't use code coverage for build acceptance purposes.  Code coverage, while useful, in no way underpins our testing or QA strategy.

Comment: I agree with smacl. In our embedded automotive projects we aim at an 80% coverage. If we have less than that we need to investigate and report why we don't reach it. Usually we don't test all failure cases and some error handlers don't get used during our test cases.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of years ago [I measured Perl's test coverage](http://books.google.gr/books?id=vEN-ckcdtCwC&pg=PA443&lpg=PA443&dq=perl+test+coverage+spinellis&source=web&ots=sF1me24MtH&sig=OJbnYuZjM0EMSDMyWkkEObc33jo&hl=en&sa=X&oi=book_result&resnum=3&ct=result).  By the end of 250 test cases it reached 70% of the code and 33% of fully tested branches

Answer (score 0):

0% sadly at our workplace yet.
Will aim to improve that but trying to tell the bosses that we need it, it isn't easy since they see testing != coding less money.

Comment: re: bosses. That is a tough sell, Forser. Of course you and I know that testing == catching bugs early == less money expended dealing with problems.  Because that is a "3-way" equation, it is often hard to relate to non-techies

Answer (score 0):

A project I did a couple of years ago achieved 100% line coverage but I had total control over it so I could enforce the target.
We've now got an objective to have 50% of new code covered, a figure that will rise in the near future, but no way to measure it.  We will soon have tools in place to measure code coverage on every nightly run of the unit tests, so I'm convinced our position will improve.