# Code coverage statistics on major projects

Tags: testing, code-coverage

I am trying to find out the code coverage statistics on major projects/major companies:

For example:

1. What is the code coverage of the PERL code base? According to one of the answers on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194836/what-is-the-code-coverage-percentage-on-your-project), it is 70%
2. What is the code coverage of some of the projects at Microsoft?
3. Any other libraries for which these statistics are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Plenty of Java projects, code coverage and much more are available on [Nemo](http://nemo.sonarsource.org).
2. Amazing document: [How SQLite Is Tested](http://www.sqlite.org/testing.html).

Comment: awesome answers   - just what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

According to this 2007 by B-Harry, the code coverage minimum bar for TFS project is set at 70% [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2007/05/07/managing-quality-part-7-code-coverage.aspx)